# Disabling tornado's python login template

Tags: php, python, redis, tornado

I downloaded an example of a tornado project form the following: https://github.com/nellessen/Tornado-Redis-Chat . **I'm trying to implement my own php session login which connects to my database instead of using the creator's original python cookie login** which can be found in auth.py & base.py of the GitHub project.

```
class LoginHandler(BaseHandler, tornado.auth.GoogleMixin):
    """
    Handler for logins with Google Open ID / OAuth
    http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/auth.html#google
    """
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def get(self):
        if self.get_argument("openid.mode", None):
            self.get_authenticated_user(self.async_callback(self._on_auth))
            return
        elif self.get_argument("start_google_oauth", None):
            # Set users attributes to ask for.
            ax_attrs = ['name', 'email', 'language', 'username']
            self.authenticate_redirect(ax_attrs=ax_attrs)
        elif self.get_argument("start_direct_auth", None):
            # Get form inputs.
            try:
                user = dict()
                user["email"] = self.get_argument("email", default="")
                user["name"] = self.get_argument("name", default="")
            except:
                # Send an error back to client.
                content = "<p>There was an input error. Fill in all fields!</p>"
                self.render_default("index.html", content=content)
            # If user has not filled in all fields.
            if not user["email"] or not user["name"]:
                content = ('<h2>2. Direct Login</h2>' 
                + '<p>Fill in both fields!</p>'
                + '<form class="form-inline" action="/login" method="get"> '
                + '<input type="hidden" name="start_direct_auth" value="1">'
                + '<input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" value="' + str(user["name"]) + '"> '
                + '<input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" value="' + str(user["email"]) + '"> '
                + '<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Sign in">'
                + '</form>')
                self.render_default("login.html", content=content)
            # All data given. Log user in!
            else:
                self._on_auth(user)
```

**PHP**

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
session_start(); 
error_reporting(0); 

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);

        $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "toot", "?*****"); // Establishing Connection with Server
$db = mysql_select_db("snape", $connection); // Selecting Database from Server
        $sql="SELECT * FROM accs WHERE name='$username' and password='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
$check = mysql_query("SELECT active FROM accs WHERE name = '$username'");
while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($check)){
      $active = $rows['active'];
}

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count!=1){
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
elseif ($active == 0) {
echo "Your account isn't active!";
}
else {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username; 
}
$time = time();
$setLogged= mysql_query("UPDATE accs SET loginstatus = '$time' WHERE name = '$username'") or die(mysql_error());
}
}
?>
```

I've made my php login and modified the html inside the login.html but the login still continued to work with the python cookie login completely ignoring my php code. I then attempted to disable the cookie login by commenting it out but then the entire login totally stopped working.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I only see python code here, where is your PHP code?